# underlying provider failed on open Error in Asp.Net MVC 4 Application

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the error saying underlying provider failed on open Error in Asp.Net MVC 4 Application when I try to query database using entityframework

Here is my connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="=ResultsContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1,13874; Initial Catalog= MySampleApplication; User id=sa; Password=Password; Integrated Security=False;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have tested the connection using x.UDL file. I am able to establish the connection successfully.

Where as the mvc4 application unable to open the connection.
What might be the issue.

I have tried all other possibilities which are posted in stackoverflow for same kind of questions.
but it gives me no luck.

Comment: Data Source=127.0.0.1,13874... is this data source correct one?
where have you posted your connection string? in MVC app's web.config or in app.config file of your edmx?

Comment: if your edmx is in different project then verify connection string in App.config file and also do check exception detail, it will show actual connection string which is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Database Server on the same machine as the Web Server?

If not then this would be the problem part

> ...Data Source=127.0.0.1,13874;...

Another problem could be log in restrictions with the `sa` account.

Answer (score 0):

As late documentation for other surfers (Visual Studio 2015):

I have struggled with this problem for some time. I have realized that the firewall was breaking the handshake process, but this happened only if I started a connection from my App by starting a debug session, thus using the session string from Web.config. Creating a connection by the Server Browser worked fine.

Have a look at this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

This is a superb systematic review of all possible system components that may disturb a connection. According to this, the connection is established by the help of the SQL Server Browser process, which uses UDP port 1434, but answers on a different IP address (preventing "Loose Target Mapping"). This is probably where the firewall must be configured a bit more sophisticated, or a server connection alias must be defined.